# Running a macro on double clicking any cell in a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to run a common macro when I double click on any of the cells of my excel sheet.
Say when I double click the cell A20, my macro will capture the column number & row number.

And for this intersection of column & row proceed with my next step.
The macro is as below for e.g:

```
Sub Trial()    
    Dim x, y As Integer

    x = ActiveCell.Column
    y = ActiveCell.Row

    Dim input1, input2 As String

    input1 = Range(x & "2").Value
    input2 = Range("A" & y).Value
End Sub
```

The result will be used in another macro for calling a SQL query -

```
Select  Sum(value)
From    Table
Where
    column1 = 'input1' and
    column2 = 'input2'
```

I just need the step to how to call my macro when I double click on any of the cell.

[image: overview]

Comment: Note that if you declare `Dim x, y As Integer` that `x` is of type `Variant` you must declare a type for **every** variable. Also row counting variables must be of type `Long` because Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle: `Dim x As Long, y As Long` • Same for your 2 string variables. • Also `x & "2"` will eg for `x = 3` result in `"32"` are you sure that this is what you expected? Because this is no valid address that can be used in a `Range()`.

Comment: You should call the Trial sub from Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick and pass Target into Trial as a parameter to avoid using ActiveCell.

Comment: I'll use the Cells() code instead of Range(). Also thanks for the variable declaration info!

Comment: My main problem was calling out the macro through double clicking, the same has been resolved.

Answer (score 3):

Right-click the sheet tab and choose `View Code`.

Select `Worksheet` from the first (Object) drop-down list at the top of the window, and select `BeforeDoubleClick` from the second (Procedure) drop-down. This generates a procedure stub:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

End Sub
```

It is in here that you can write your code. You can check the `Target` to only respond to a certain range of cells, and use `Cancel` to cancel any default double-clicking behaviour.

For example, the following will confirm which range was double-clicked:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox Target.Address

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    MsgBox "Row:" & Target.Row & vbNewLine & "Column:" & Target.Column

End Sub
```

**Image:**

[image]